# Targeting a div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to target the first div block that wraps "Target".

```
<div class="box-content">
<div>
    <div>Target</div>
    <div>xxxx</div>
    <div>xxxx</div>
    <div>xxxx</div>
    <div>
       <div>Unwanted</div>
       <p>xxxx</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried;

```
div.box-content div div:nth-child(1)  {
display:none;
}
```

and

```
div.box-content div div:first-child {
display:none;
}
```

but it removes the div that wraps "Unwanted" too. How can I target only the first one that wraps "Target"

Comment: Are you missing a </div> for box-content there?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Can you point to exactly which div you want to select? Your code seems to be looking for "Target" itself, but you're asking for the one that wraps "Target"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select the direct children, like:

```
div.box-content > div > div:first-child {
  display:none;
}
```

Your original code selects any `div:first-child`, who has a `div` as an ancestor (not a necessarily a direct parent), which also is an ancestor of `div.box-content`... in other words, there's no constraint to just your `Target` and `Unwanted` also falls into this.

The code above uses the `>` selector, which says `div:first-child` should be styled only when it is a **direct child** of a `div`, which is also a **direct child** of `div.box-content`